# How to resize modal from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to modal pop-up from the bootstrap. I am currently using here a modal from the examples on w3schools. I want to insert my input form inside the modal. So when the user click the *Upload File button*, this modal will pop-up. Here is the photo: [(Please take a look at this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QggFj.png)

---

As you can see, my problem here is the input fields are unorganized, I just **want to resize the modal so the input fields would fit in.** How can I achieve that? Your help will be highly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<!-- ******** LOG IN MODAL START ******** -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #003399;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: 
       #fff;">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff;">Upload New File</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="uploadfile.php" method="post" 
       name="addservice" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center" 
       onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="filename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">File Name:
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" 
             name="filename" id="filename" placeholder="Name of the file" 
             maxlength="55" tabindex="1" required></div>
        <!--  </div>

        <div class="form-group"> -->
          <label for="file" class="col-sm-2">File:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="file" maxlength="11" 
            name="file" id="file" class="form-control" tabindex="2" 
            required></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="filedesc" class="col-sm-2">File Description:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4"><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" 
           name=" filedesc" id="filedesc" placeholder="(maximum of 75 
           characters)" style="resize: none;" maxlength="75" tabindex="3" 
           required></textarea></div>
        </div>


    </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-
          sm-4" name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" tabindex="4">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-sm-4" 
            name="clear" value="Clear" tabindex="5">
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- modal body -->

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

  </div>  <!-- modal content -->

</div> <!-- modal dialog -->
</div>  <!-- modal fade -->
<!-- ******** LOG IN MODAL END ******** -->
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rmoxdpmq/ - probably `col-sm-4` div around buttons is causing problems; also, you can use `.modal-lg` class for larger modal - https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Comment: The above  comment is probably what you are looking for but what you also could do is `<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">`  and to make sure the elements inside are displayed properly use `padding`

Comment: @hansTheFranz great it actually works, i'll just adjust the buttons thank you

Comment: happy to help but my solution isn't really good. You should look out for a responsive solution. Try to use "%" instead of "px" or even better search for a Bootstrap solution like @Morpheus suggested.

Answer (score 0):

please check that this might help you:

Small Modal

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

Large Modal

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

here is the example:




        <div class="container">
          <h2>Small Modal</h2>
          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->


        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>This is a small modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```